# JSON error "Expecting value: line 2 column 11 (char 12)"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am running the below code to fetch the data from an apache kafka consumer in python.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

consumer = KafkaConsumer("DataEngFuelData", bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], group_id=None,
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest')
try:
    for msg in consumer:
        decoded_msg = msg.value.decode('utf-8-sig')
        decoded_msgtmp = json.loads(decoded_msg)
        print(decoded_msgtmp)
        dictmsg = decoded_msgtmp['stations']
        print(dictmsg)

except Exception as e:      
    print(e)
```

However, when the program executes the json.loads() function it gives me the error

```
Expecting value: line 2 column 11 (char 12).
```

Comment: Have you looked at the value in decoded_msg to see if it is malformed?

Comment: Yes it gives me string object.
<class 'str'>
    "Stations":{
            "Id": "2645B215-8233-49Dc-85F4-B389B284F624",
            "Name": "Aral Tankstelle",
            "Brand": "Aral",
            "Street": "Bergheimer Stra\U00Dfe",
            "Place": "Heidelberg"
}

Even though I have decoded it it is giving me strings like "Street": "Bergheimer Stra\U00Dfe" in the output. can this cause any issue?

Comment: How is data produced into the topic? Do you trust its always valid JSON? Why are you using `utf-8-sig`? And why aren't you passing a value deserailizer into the consumer class?

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks for your help